# python -X showrefcount reporting negative reference counts for extension

Tags: python, garbage-collection, cpython

When I run cpython with the `-X showrefcount` flag on an extension I'm writing, it reports a negative reference count (e.g. `[-5538 refs, 13503 blocks]`) when I return None from a function (using the `Py-RETURN_NONE` macro).

#### Known facts:

- The exact count varies between runs, but remains within the same order of magnitude.
- Whatever is happening, it seems to happen slowly; I need to call the extension function approximately 50,000 times before the reference count goes negative.
- If we replace `Py_RETURN_NONE;` with `Py_INCREF(Py_None); return Py_None;`, it
  changes nothing. Indeed, we can seemingly add an arbitrary number of `Py_INCREF(Py_None)`s without affecting the reference count at all.
- If we replace `Py_RETURN_NONE;` with `return Py_None;` and *don't* increment the reference count, it segfaults (as expected).
- If we replace the None return with another value, e.g. `PyLong_FromLong(0);`, the problem vanishes.

What is the cause of this? Related question: why is the reference count not *zero* after running an empty script?

## Minimal Example:

### build command used for cpython debug build

```
$ ./configure --with-pydebug --with-valgrind && make
```

### extension.c

```
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>

static PyObject *f(void) {
    int manifest_bug = 1;
    if (manifest_bug) {
        Py_RETURN_NONE;
    }
    else {
        return PyLong_FromLong(0);
    }
}

static PyMethodDef functions[] = {
    {"f", (PyCFunction)f, METH_NOARGS, "" },
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL},
};

static struct PyModuleDef module = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    .m_name = "foo",
    .m_size = -1,
    .m_methods = functions,
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_foo(void) {
    return PyModule_Create(&module);
}
```

### setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension

name="foo"
def main() -> None:
    setup(
        name=name,
        version="0.0.0",
        ext_modules=[ Extension(name, ["extension.c"]) ],
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

### test.py

```
import foo
# With fewer than roughly this many iterations, the reference count
# generally remains positive. With more iterations, it becomes more negative
for i in range(50000):
    foo.f()
```

Comment: Which python version? How do you build the c-extension? IIRC correctly mixing debug and release prior to 3.8 had funny effects.

Comment: @ead Looks like that's at least part of the problem. The debug build was the latest 3.11, but I was just pointing its sys.path at my 3.6 site-packages instead of installing the a separate copy of the extension. Building under 3.11 eliminates the negative reference counts, although it still reports ~24k references on termination (for the real script and the empty script).

Comment: And how big is this number without running the script? I assume still quite high. There are objects in python interpreter, which stay alive until the interpreter dies and nobody cares about bringing their refcount to 0.

Comment: @ead ~24k references (if running the repl and terminating immediately instead of running an empty file, it reports two values, 100k and 55k, for some reason). I suspect you're right, and it's just the interpreter letting the OS free the memory for it.  If so, your comments together answer the question completely. Might be worth putting them in an answer for the benefit of anyone else who runs into this.

Comment: Feel free to answer it yourself, I don’t think I can add something of any value to my wild guesses above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to the extension having been built using an older version of python, and *run* using a debug build compiled from the latest version of the source.  Extensions not compiled using the [stable ABI](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/stable.html#stable) (and declared as doing so) are not binary compatible across python versions.

[Credit to ead's comment for asking the question that led directly to this solution.]